# Errors while Importing from BACPAC in Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, importerror, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I have a .bacpac file exported from SQL Server 2008. While I'm trying to import the same in my Azure SQL Server using latest SSMS, I'm thrown the below error at a specific Table.

===================================

## Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

### One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)

===================================

## One or more errors occurred.

## One or more errors occurred.

The given key was not present in the dictionary. (mscorlib)

===================================

Can somebody please help me on this?

Many Thanks,
Suhail

Comment: Is it possible that your database changed  (data added/removed) while the  BACPAC file was being exported?

Comment: No! I did export it in a separate session several times though.

Comment: Did you got the resolution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Are any of the tables or columns named with unusual characters?  Such as a table with a column named something like '[columnname].columnname' instead of just 'columnname'?  That turned out to be the issue in our case - rename the column to a more standard name.